# Java Performance concern in Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions, unchecked-exception

I am aware of the Checked and Unchecked Exception in Java.

In a multi-tiered environment, does unchecked Exception has a better performance over checked Exception?

Comment: Absolutely zero performance difference. They're both just `Exception`s. Checked/unchecked is purely a compile-time concept.

Comment: Gentleman, down vote comments please.

Comment: Don't look at me, I didn't DV. And I'm probably the only person who would be notified or notice on a comment on a 2-week-old question.

Comment: Good, because I have no particular incentive to lie; I could just stay quiet... Now, what is wrong with my answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely zero performance difference. They're both just `Exception`s.

Checked-/unchecked-ness is purely a compile-time concept.

Comment: is unchecked exception " compile-time concept" ??

Comment: As far as I can see, [11.3. Run-Time Handling of an Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3) draws no distinction between unchecked and checked exceptions - it doesn't even mention the terms.

Comment: @Rehman A checked exception is verified by the compiler to be either caught (`try-catch`) or listed in the `throws` clause of the method. There is no run-time check for that. See "[Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2)" and "[Run-Time Handling of an Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3)" in the JLS. Therefore, the *difference* between checked and unchecked is a compile-time concept.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer. :-)